# NSCoding and GameplayKit Classes

Tags: swift, nscoding, gameplay-kit

In my game I have a NSCoding-conforming Combat class, which also uses GameplayKit's GKGridGraph and GKGridGraphNode objects, which do not conform to NSCoding. Is there a way to serialize/unserialize these objects?

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, there's no `NSCoding` support in these classes. (That'd make a good [feature request to send to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com), though.)

It should be possible, however, to create your own serialized representation of a graph when encoding your classes, then read that in and initialize new `GKGraph` and `GKGraphNode` objects accordingly in your `init(coder:)` implementation. Note that when doing so you'll have to carefully walk the graph yourself to capture all the node connections.